# Trying to create a "general" logging solution for requests in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, logback, interceptor

I'm currently trying to create a info log for every request in the API I'm working on, but instead of creating a log for every request at the controller level, I wanted to try creating a "catch all" solution but I'm not being able to fullfill my goals.

I've decided to start the idea using Spring's @Aspect annotation, but using it isn't the best idea because I'd have to create one aspect for every controller that I have.

After some digging I found 2 possible solution paths that I could try to work on, @ControllerAdvice and creating an interceptor (which in theory is the one idea that I think has the most chances of succeeding and being a clean solution).

The problem is that I'm not being able to find much information regarding these ideas.

For the @ControllerAdvice idea I'm only finding it being used to handle exceptions, and for the interceptor idea I'm not finding anything similar to what I want to create.

Are these ideas feasible at all? Or should I just stick to logging everything at controller level?

Not sure if it's important but I'm currently working using LogBack library.

Comment: Look here for the interceptor solution: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor

Answer (score 0):

There is a ready solution for complete request and response logging for different client- and server-side technologies.
I'm using **logbook** tool for tracking request-response info for my rest endpoints.

https://github.com/zalando/logbook